# Application of Derivatives : Tangent to a parabola

Tags: calculus, derivatives, applications

[image]

I am trying to solve the question in the image above. Here is how I tried :

[image]

I am stuck at this point.**How should I solve I further?** AND **Second derivative is independent of x then how to decide between f"(0) and f"(1).**

Comment: @Arby it is been said axis of parabola is parallel to y axis..... does it mean we have to make a f (x) form function onlyl or can we solve as I approached?

Comment: I'm trying to follow your line of reasoning, but it's taking me a while. If you are doing things right, it probably will lead to the correct answer though it will most likely be more complicated and less elegant. Doug M's answer below is very, very nice and I think your time would be better spent figuring out how to do it that way for future reference. Especially his first step, very nice.

Comment: @Arby okay. I'll be trying myself. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll do it your way first.

Following what you wrote, you know that $f'(x) = \frac{x-h}{2a}$, and you know that $f''(x) = \frac{1}{2a}.$
Also, near the bottom of the first page you have written that 
$$1-h=2a.\tag1$$ 
This is important, because it is equivalent to the equation 
$\frac{1-h}{2a}=1,$ which is equivalent to the fact that
$f'(1) = 1,$ which is what we learn from the fact that the parabola is
tangent to the line $y=x$ at $x=1.$

At the very bottom of the page you have found that
$$f'(1) + f''(x) = \frac{2-h}{2a}.\tag2$$
(I have translated what you wrote from the Leibniz notation that you used into the notation used in the question.)

Notice that there is only one choice among the multiple-choice answers that matches Equation $2,$ and that's choice (d).
But if choice (d) is the correct answer, then
$f'(1) + f''(x) = f''(0) + f'(1) = 1,$
which implies that $\frac{2-h}{2a} = 1,$ which implies $2-h=2a.$
But you already know that $1-h=2a$ (Equation $1$).
Is it possible both equations are true?
Is it possible that $2-h=1-h$?
No, so (d) is not the correct answer.

If you write out an equation for choice (b), you end up with
$\frac{1}{2a} - \frac{1-h}{2a} = 1.$
Again, you also know that $\frac{1-h}{2a} = 1.$
Can this be true? Yes, if $h = \frac12.$ But how can you show that $h=\frac12$? Hmm, not looking good, maybe we'll come back to this later, but let's give the other choices a chance.

Choices (a) and (c) evaluate the derivatives at different points 
than (b) and (d): $f''(1)$ and $f'(0).$
But you already know that $f''(1)= \frac{1}{2a}$ and 
$f'(0) = \frac{0 - h}{2a} = -\frac{h}{2a}.$
Try this with choice (a), 
which says that $f''(1) + f'(0) = 1.$
Is it true that $\frac{1}{2a}+\left(-\frac{h}{2a}\right)=1$?
Yes, if $\frac{1-h}{2a}=1.$
But we know this is true, because Equation $1$ is true.
So (a) is correct.

---

I consider that the hard way to do this problem. 
The easy way is, since I know $f''(x)$ is constant,
I know $y=f'(x)$ is the equation of a line of slope $m = f''(x).$
Writing the equation of this line in $y$-intercept form,
I find that
$$f'(x) = f'(0) + m x.\tag3$$
I happen to notice that $f'(1) = 1,$ since the parabola is tangent to 
a line of slope $1$ at $x=1,$ so putting $x=1$ in Equation $3$ I have
$$1 = f'(0) + m,$$
where $m$ is the second derivative of $f$ evaluated at any point.
I could replace $m$ with $f''(0)$ or with $f''(1),$ whichever is more convenient.
Looking at the choices, I think $f''(1)$ is more convenient, because then I have $1 = f'(0) + f''(1),$
so I know that at least choice (a) is correct.

Comment: Thank you. Your answers is the one I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

$y(1) = 1\\
y = (x-1)(ax+b) + 1$

$y'(x) = (ax+b) + a(x-1)\\
y'(1) = 1\\
b = 1-a\\
y'(0) = 1-2a$

$y''(1) = y''(0) = 2a$

a) is the only one that fits.

Comment: Thanks you. I have a request, please help me solve by my approach cause I cannot solve by that method.

Comment: locking yourself into the $4ay = (x-h)^2 + k$ format is going to make for more work for you.  My choice of formats might be a little odd, but it is a generic parabola that goes through the point $(1,1).$  Anyway, the key details is that $f'(1) = 1.$  This will force your coefficients to a limited set of values.  From there you can find $f''(x),$ and $f'(x)$

Answer (score 0):

General form of parabola $$f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$$

We are given that the line $y=x$ touches the parabola at $x=1$, which implies that the gradient of the parabola at $x=1$ is given by the gradient of $y=x$

Hence $f'(1) = 1$, and $f(1) = 1$

Plugging this in, we get:

$$f'(x) = 2ax + b \implies f'(1) = 2a + b = 1 \implies b=1-2a$$

$$f(1) = a+b+c = 1$$

Also, $$f''(x) = 2a$$

So then $$f''(x)-f'(x) = 2a-2ax-b = 2a-2ax+2a-1 =4a-2ax-1$$

$$f'(x)+f''(x) = 2ax+b+2a = 2ax+1-2a+2a = 2ax+1$$

It seems like $f'(x)+f''(x)$ will fit one of those expressions.

Also note that $f''(x)$ is independent of $x$

$$f''(1)+f'(0) = 1$$

Note that $$f''(0)+f'(1) =2a+1$$ which doesn't necessarily equal $1$

Therefore the answer is $(a)$

Comment: Thank you. I always get helpful answers from you people. Can I request one more thing. Please help me to solve further following my approach.l because I could not solve by that method.

Comment: @user411518 Sure, but may I ask why you chose that as your equation of your parabola - it seems to complicate the matter